# Getters and Setters são gerados automaticamente pelo Eloquente quando usamos reliese/laravel para gerar os Módulos?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, orm

Eu tenho uma aplicação já funcional. Estou passando para laravel 5.4.
Dado que o banco de dados já existe e com dados reais, a minha escolha é não utilizar Migrations. Uma opção seria usar o [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) para acessar os dados no banco de dados. Mas eu não queria deixar para trás algumas conveniências oferecidas pelo Eloquente. Por isso resolvi importar o modelo do banco de dados no ORM usando o [reliese/laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel), e ao final do processo os Modelos são criado na pasta **app/Models/MinhaTabela.php**.

Como eu sou iniciante no Laravel eu não sei quais os métodos que são criados automaticamente quando geramos os Modelos. Me chamou a atenção que não foram criados getters and setters automaticamente para cada campo ou atributuo de cada  tabela. Em Sinfony existe uma função do Doctrine, que após criado as Entities (equivalente aos Modelos no Eloquente) essa função gera getters and setterspara cada campo da tabela.

Esse é um exmplo do código gerado automaticamente para o **Modelo** da tabela **Country**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by Reliese Model.
 * Date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017 02:14:38 +0000.
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Reliese\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

/**
 * Class Country
 * 
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $iso3_code
 * @property string $iso2_code
 * @property string $geocodeBr
 * @property float $lat
 * @property float $long
 * 
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $provinces
 *
 * @package App\Models
 */
class Country extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'country';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'lat' => 'float',
        'long' => 'float'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'iso3_code',
        'iso2_code',
        'geocodeBr',
        'lat',
        'long'
    ];

    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Province::class, 'fk_country');
    }
}
```

Como se vê, praticamente nada foi criado, eu teria que criar os setters and getters and put delete, etc, para cada campo de cada tabela.

Quando possuimos um banco de dados com 200 tabelas isso fica um tédio.

Então a minha pergunta é se os getters and setters são gerados automaticamente por algum comando do Eloquente ou eu teria que criar automaticamente cada um deles? Se sim que comando seria esse?

Comment: O Elqouent não geram métodos `get/setter` como por exemplo `getId()` e `setId($value)`, na verdade seria `id, name, ` os nomes que estão em sua tabela. Nada impede que você crie na mão, mas, já relatou que é inconveniente, também acredito que seja, acho eu desnecessário, porque o Eloquent faz isso diferente e é um código adicional sem necessidade, use a nomenclatura padrão ...

Comment: Como eu disse, sou novato no Laravel. Dei uma pesquisada e achei depois que não precisamos de getters and setters, como vc disse. Quando o Model extend a classe Eloquente ele já herda as funções da classe Eloquent que seriam getters and setters, como por exemplo self::all(), que seria o getAll(). E assim por diante...

Comment: nem tudo que você disse na mensagem acima é assim gera automáticamente tem mais coisas a aprender sobre Laravel que na verdade é PHP, continue estudando ... @zwitterion